# Will this prevent image caching on external pages? looking for a solution

Tags: caching

i store images on my server.
Other websites/ pages can display these images.
I want to prevent old images showing on other pages after i changed these on my server.

Other websites can use this code:

```
<a href="link" target="_blank">
<img src="https://www.example.com/image.gif?1222259157.415"/>
</a>
```

*where "1222259157.415" is a random number and never changes.
Will this prevent caching?
Or will the image (image.gif?1222259157.415) be cached.
If this works, i can replace image.gif on my server and it will display this new image on the other websites too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will. THis is a typical cache busting approach.

You could make the number not random but i.e. a number based on the file write time. Anything that only changes when the image changes, so caching STILL applies for repeated loads of the same unchanged image.